# How to load amp html in mobile version

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html, google-amp

I have 2 html's like non-amp.html and amp.html.

I included

```
<link rel="canonical" href="app/templates/non-amp.html">
```

in my amp.html and

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="app/templates/amp-blog-list.html">
```

in my index.html.

When i kept my site in mobile view the desktop html (non-amp)is loading.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

think about how does your application or website know if a visitor is using a mobile or a desktop computer?

you need to write some code that detects if it is a mobile, tablet, desktop and further depending on your requirements.

then when a mobile device has been detected you can then write to the page the required code you want to show.

I would recommend having a look at the following Question on stack overflow as the answer you need has already been given here.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Answer (score 0):

In mobile and Desktop both show the non amp pages :

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="app/templates/amp-blog-list.html"> This tag is for google to know the amp page in non amp file.
```

Once you come from google search in mobile devices your amp page is open in google iframe.